# CRMServiceClient does not try to connect to Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Using the latest SDK for Dynamics CRM, I am attempting to create a new CRMServiceClient([ConnectionString]).  I try to do anything with it including a WHOAMI request, and I get Unable to Login to Dynamics OrganizationServiceProxy is null.  When I run fiddler, nothing is even attempting to communicate to the server to attempt a login.  I am unsure what is wrong, as I would have thought newing up a CRMServiceClient would have tried to connect since OrganizationServiceProxy is a child object of CRMServiceClient.  Anyone have any ideas how to approach solving this?

```
var temp = new CrmServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con‌​n"].ConnectionString‌​);
```

```xml
<add name="conn" connectionString="AuthType=AD; Url=Url/DEVCRM; Username=User; Password=pass;"/>
```

Comment: Please share your code and exception details. With the information you provided it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Most likely your connection string is bad, but with the information you provided it's not possible to help you

Comment: var temp = new CrmServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString); 

<add name="conn" connectionString="AuthType=AD; Url=https://Url/DEVCRM; Username=User; Password=pass;"/>

So when I run the 1 line of code, the OrganizationServiceProxy is null.  the connection string is above as well. Changed URL, Username and password to hide true information.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that CrmServiceClient has a boolean property called [IsReady](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient.isready.aspx), which is a good way to check if it's in a proper state.

And for reference, here are example connection strings for the various environment types:

CRM 2016 and Dynamics 365 online:

```
<add name="dev26" connectionString="Url=https://dev26.crm.dynamics.com; Username=user@dev26.onmicrosoft.com; Password=Pass; AuthType=Office365" />
```

On-premise with integrated security:

```
<add name="prod" connectionString="Url=http://myserver/AdventureWorksCycle;"/>
```

On-premise with credentials:

```
<add name="prod" connectionString="Url=http://myserver/AdventureWorksCycle; Domain=mydomain; Username=administrator; Password=password; AuthType=AD;"/>
```

On-premise IFD before CRM 2016:

```
<add name="prod" connectionString="Url=https://contoso.litware.com; Username=someone@litware.com; Password=password; AuthType=IFD;"/>
```

On-premise IFD for CRM 2016 and later (v8.0+)

```
<add name="prod" connectionString="ServiceUri=https://contoso.litware.com/contoso; Domain=contoso; Username=contoso\administrator; Password=password; AuthType=IFD; LoginPrompt=Never;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your connectionstring I would suggest you to add domain to it. That should resolve your issue. Check following example:

> Named account using on-premises authentication

```
<add name="MyCRMServer"connectionString="AuthType=AD;Url=http://contoso:8080/Test;Domain=CONTOSO; Username=jsmith; Password=passcode" />
```

You can find more information in following article - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt608573.aspx

Comment: I have also used this format:

AuthType=AD;Url=https://[server]/DEVCRM;Domain=[Domain];Username=[user(no domain)];Password=[pass]"

I still get a null OrganizationServiceProxy.  I can login to the dynamics instance at the URL with the username and password just find.

Comment: Does the CrmServiceClient connect to CRM in the constructor?  If so, shouldn't Fiddler see it?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that .net 4.6.2 doesn't play nicely with the CRM SDK, if you are running that version of .net upgrade or downgrade the framework installed on your computer.

[Updating to .net 4.6.2 from .net 4.5.2 causing Object Reference Exception on ExecuteCore method within xrm sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937875/updating-to-net-4-6-2-from-net-4-5-2-causing-object-reference-exception-on-exe)

If that isn't the cause, enable tracing to get more detailed error messages, see following article for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dn689064.aspx