# Can't Access MS CRM Dynamic 365 by C# code

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, console-application, office365, dynamics-365

I have a problem when try to connect to MS CRM v9

I used this code to connect:

```
Uri organizationUri = new Uri(OrgUrl);
AuthenticationCredentials authCredentials = new AuthenticationCredentials();
authCredentials.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = UserName;
authCredentials.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Password;
OrganizationServiceProxy organizationProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(organizationUri, null, authCredentials.ClientCredentials, null);
organizationProxy.EnableProxyTypes();`
var _service = organizationProxy;
```

This is the Exception message

> HResult=-2146233079   Message=Metadata contains a reference that
>   cannot be resolved:
>   'https://myOrg.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl&sdkversion=9'.
>   InnerException: 
>          HResult=-2146233079
>          Message=The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. 
>          InnerException: 
>               HResult=-2146232800
>               Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>               InnerException: 
>                    ErrorCode=10054
>                    HResult=-2147467259
>                    Message=An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Did anyone face this problem before. PS: this code is running before in the same project

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need to update your SDK references to the new 9.0 SDK references.  There isn't a single download any more for the SDK, instead you have to use NuGet (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2017/11/01/whats-new-for-customer-engagement-developer-documentation-in-version-9-0/)

> No more monolithic SDK download
>   Probably the greatest single change is that we are no longer providing a single download package for all the documentation, tools and sample code.  Going forward, instead of shipping a single package with everything in it, we will offer an a-la-carte approach so that you can download the individual things as you need them.
>
> **Get the assemblies and tools you need.** SDK assemblies and tools will be distributed only via NuGet. We will provide a script that will allow you to download the assemblies and tools from NuGet. See Where to find the NuGet SDK packages and Download tools from NuGet.
>
> **Self-serve offline content generation.** The new learn.microsoft.com site will allow you to download a PDF for any of our content areas so that you can read and search the documentation while offline.
>
> **Sample code availability.** All our sample code will be available on msdn.microsoft.com or on GitHub. The code.msdn.microsoft.com site is designed for sample code and provides a good experience as well as providing us better metrics on usage.
>
> **Download only the pieces you need.** Various assets we have included in the download package will be available as individual downloads. This way, if one of the assets needs to be updated we can just update it without releasing the entire SDK package.

https://www.nuget.org/profiles/crmsdk has a list of all the SDK DLLs you might need.  Specifically https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly/ includes the Connector which is what I think you actually need.

You can add it to your project using the following command in your NuGet console

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly -Version 9.0.0.7
```

If you don't need a specific version you can just use

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly
```

Comment: Point of clarification: Is there a compelling reason to be explicit with the Nuget package version?

Comment: Thanks for your replay Mauro, I'm already using this Version 9.0.0.7 but still issue is there

Comment: @Basic nope - its just the example from the specific page :)

Answer (score 0):

I generally use [CrmServiceClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient.aspx) in the `Xrm.Tooling.Connector` namespace, with a connection string.

`var svc = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);`

Please note that CrmServiceClient has a boolean property called [IsReady](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient.isready.aspx), which is a good way to check if it's in a proper state.

Here are example connection strings for the various environment types. These are hardcoded examples, but you can also add them to the App.Config as shown in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106805/crmserviceclient-does-not-try-to-connect-to-dynamics-crm/45113466#45113466).

CRM 2016 and Dynamics 365 online:

```
var connectionString = "Url=https://dev26.crm.dynamics.com; Username=user@dev26.onmicrosoft.com; Password=Pass; AuthType=Office365";
```

On-premise with integrated security:

```
var connectionString="Url=http://myserver/AdventureWorksCycle;";
```

On-premise with credentials:

```
var connectionString="Url=http://myserver/AdventureWorksCycle; Domain=mydomain; Username=administrator; Password=password; AuthType=AD;";
```

On-premise IFD before CRM 2016:

```
var connectionString="Url=https://contoso.litware.com; Username=someone@litware.com; Password=password; AuthType=IFD;";
```

On-premise IFD for CRM 2016 and later (v8.0+)

```
var connectionString="ServiceUri=https://contoso.litware.com/contoso; Domain=contoso; Username=contoso\administrator; Password=password; AuthType=IFD; LoginPrompt=Never;";`
```