# OrganizationServiceProxy cannot be initialised after dlls are merged using ILMERGE

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, ilmerge

I have created a windows form application in C# (.NET 4.6.2). I am using the below piece of code to connect to Dynamics 365 online:

```
ClientCredentials clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "XXXXX@XXX.onmicrosoft.com";
clientCredentials.UserName.Password = "XXXXXXXX";

Uri crmURL = new Uri("https://XXXXX.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
using (OrganizationServiceProxy orgaSvcProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(crmURL, null, clientCredentials, null))
{
    IOrganizationService orgaService = (IOrganizationService)orgaSvcProxy;
    if (orgaService != null)
    {
        Guid userid = ((WhoAmIResponse)orgaService.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest())).UserId;
        if (userid != Guid.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection established successfully");
        }
    }
}
```

I have referenced following 2 dlls in my VS 2015 (.NET 4.6.2) project:

1. Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll
2. Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll

Everything works fine if I launch the windows form from VS IDE or launch the windows form using exe file. But if I **merge the exe and above mentioned two dlls in a single exe file using ILMERGE** and launch the windows form using merged exe then following line of code starts failing:

> OrganizationServiceProxy orgaSvcProxy = new
>   OrganizationServiceProxy(crmURL, null, clientCredentials, null)

Above line of code throws following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceMetadataUtility.GetSDKVersionNumberFromAssembly()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceMetadataUtility.RetrieveServiceEndpointMetadata(Type
>   contractType, Uri serviceUri, Boolean checkForSecondary)    at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1..ctor(Uri serviceUri,
>   Boolean checkForSecondary)    at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceConfiguration..ctor(Uri
>   serviceUri, Boolean enableProxyTypes, Assembly assembly)    at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration[TService](Uri
>   serviceUri, Boolean enableProxyTypes, Assembly assembly)    at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration[TService](Uri
>   serviceUri)    at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceProxy`1..ctor(Uri
>   uri, Uri homeRealmUri, ClientCredentials clientCredentials,
>   ClientCredentials deviceCredentials)    at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy..ctor(Uri uri, Uri
>   homeRealmUri, ClientCredentials clientCredentials, ClientCredentials
>   deviceCredentials)    at
>   ElevateCRMAccess.fmElevateCRMAcces.btnElevate_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

I have used following line to merge assemblies using ILMERGE:

```
"$(SolutionDir)ILMERGE/IlMerge.exe" /target:winexe /targetplatform:"v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" /out:"$(SolutionDir)..\Output\ConnectToCRM.exe" "$(TargetDir)ConnectToCRM.exe" "$(TargetDir)Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll" "$(TargetDir)Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll"
```

Could someone please help identify the issue here. What is causing the merged exe to be failed.

Answer (score 0):

The state of the art for using the SDK to connect to Dynamics 365 (a.k.a. CDS) from an external app is [CrmServiceClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient?view=dynamics-xrmtooling-ce-9), which is available in the [Xrm Tooling](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly/) NuGet package.

Once you add that NuGet package to your project, you're ready to go.

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector;
var svc = new CrmServiceClient("Url=https://dev26.crm.dynamics.com; Username=user@dev26.onmicrosoft.com; Password=Pass; AuthType=Office365");
svc.Retrieve("account", new Guid("7D9AAF71-5845-E811-A950-000D3A1D7326", new ColumnSet(true)) ;
```

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106805/crmserviceclient-does-not-try-to-connect-to-dynamics-crm/45113466#45113466) for additional connection strings.

I've been using it with .NET Framework 4.7.1+ to connect C# apps to Dynamics CRM 2013 through Dynamics 365 v9.

Whether you need to do the ILMerge or not, you might want to consider switching to XrmTooling. And if you can avoid ILMerge, all the better. For the record, [ILMerge is unsupported](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/develop1/archive/2018/10/21/if-you-re-using-ilmerge-with-your-plugins-make-sure-you-read-this) for plugins.

Comment: Thanks Aron. Even with Xrm Tooling result is the same. It's working fine when run directly in VS or with the exe in the presence of required dlls. But following error is thrown when I run the exe after merge with all the dlls: System.NullReferenceException: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)`. I am not writing this code for a plugin but want to create a standalone executable.

Comment: @Indie.Dev If it's a standalone executable why do you need to use ILMerge?

Comment: I want to distribute this executable to users without the dlls. If I don't use ILMerge then I will have to distribute exe along with the dlls. I know that will not be a problem but I am just curious why the code is failing after merge.

Comment: I have had problems merging Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll in the past. You may want to try merging all but that one.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but I just saw this question and thought maybe an answer could help people with same problem.

According to the error, the problem is that SDK is looking at the DLL to determine the SDK version (GetSDKVersionNumberFromAssembly), and when you use ILMerge to merge dlls, you are moving assembly content into a new assembly, and so SDK can not find out the version since it doesn't know your dll.

To solve the problem, you can store SDK dll as a resource in your assembly file and extract it on startup, or use a tool like [Fody Custora](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) to automate this process. The Custora output is very similar to ILMerge, but Custora don't merge ILs, it simply add external dlls as resources.